# PHP CURL log entry to file and forward POST data to another server?

Tags: php, curl, post, request, get

Coding API and I see some dead end. What needs be done?

1. Server 1 has app with form and POST submits form data via PHP CURL to logger server 2
2. Server 2 has to retrieve from data from server 1, log to a file and send to processing server 3
3. Server 3 does not seem to receive the data from the form from server 1 through server 2

Server 1 seems to send data
Server 2 does not seem to receive it, but does so when HTTP request is done through browser in address bar (GET)

Question is how to process POST data rom server 1 and send it to server 3 on server 2? Here is my code:

```
<?

// Collect data via HTTP request
$field_1    = isset($_REQUEST['field_1']) ? urldecode($_REQUEST['field_1']) : '';
$field_2    = isset($_REQUEST['field_2']) ? urldecode($_REQUEST['field_2']) : '';
$field_3    = isset($_REQUEST['field_3']) ? urldecode($_REQUEST['field_3']) : '';

// Config
$apikey     = 'bla-bla';
$url        = "https://api.some.url.dot.com/script";

// POST array data
$postdata = array(
    "field_1" => $field_1,
    "field_2" => $field_2,
    "field_3" => $field_3
);

// Fire API call
$data_string = json_encode($postdata);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'api-key:'.$apikey,
    'Content-Type:application/json'
));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
// print_r($output);
$log = $field_1.' '.$field_2.' '.$field_3;
file_put_contents('/path/to/log',$log.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
die();

?>
```

Maybe I do not understand well what POST method does? Works when data is sent to server 2 from server 1 or wherever via GET, e.g. in browser address bar - send data via query string. What am I missing?

Server 1 html form

```
    <form action="script.php" class="form" method="POST">
    <div>
        <input name="field1" placeholder="This" required type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="field2" placeholder="That" required type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="field3" placeholder="That Else" required type="text">
    </div>
<button class="btn button__text" type="submit"> SUBMIT </button>
</form>
```

and server 1 php script to POST submit data via CURL

```
   $args = array(
'field1' => urlencode($_POST[field1]),
'field2' => urlencode($_POST[field2]),
'field3' => urlencode($_POST[field3]),
);

$data = json_encode($args);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => API_URL,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)
    ),
));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Didnt you just ask this?

Comment: SO you need to show us HOW Server 1 sends the data, so we have a vague idea whats going on

Comment: @RiggsFolly, you are right. I just asked this. Did someone else ask the same? Imagine that... 
Server 1 sends the data via form and CURL POST request to server2.

Comment: ___No lets NOT IMAGINE___. Please show us the code, otherwie this too will be closed as needing more information. We cannot help debug what we cannot see

Comment: Updated question. If you have some anger issues or problems with somebody else, I do not care, dude. Thought this is a place to discuss. Not sure why you scream with all caps and all that. Go have some fun, if this here is not fun for you.

Comment: If you are struggling with a problem and one of us asks to see some more code then please assume there is a good reason for the request. A response of "image that ...." in no way helps us to help you

Comment: OK. Code posted. Not sure how it will help. It is just a form and CURL POST request

Comment: So have you checked what `API_URL` is and is it correct?

Comment: Do you check what `$result` is from this line `$result = curl_exec($curl);`

Comment: API_URL is a const and is fine.
Will check what result says. Thanks!